Cannot get a tex file to compile via a background job: No such file or directory
Background
I use vim to edit tex files and use a Dockerized LaTeX environment to compile a tex file into a pdf.
To compile the file, I have been using following function:
" function to compile LaTeX document
function! CompileDoc()
  if &filetype=='tex'
    :silent !docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm -v $(pwd):/data latex-dev:1.0.0 latexmk -pdf -silent % >/dev/null
    :silent !reloadPreview
    :redraw!
  endif
endfunction

" ctrl+p keyboard shortcut to compile LaTeX document
map <silent> <C-p> :call CompileDoc()<CR>

" autocmd BufWritePost *.tex :call CompileDoc() | noautocmd write

This works, but it causes vim to freeze during compilation (which can take some time if the document is long or complex), and the screen flashes when it gets redrawn.
After reading How do I get Vim to compile my .tex file when executing :w?, I tried to rewrite the function to take advantage of job_start:
function! RedrawScreen(channel)
  redraw!
endfunction

function! CompileTex()
  let tex_file = expand('%:p')
  let tex_cmd = 'docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm -v $(pwd):/data latex-dev:1.0.0 latexmk -pdf -silent -interaction=nonstopmode ' . tex_file
  let s:job = job_start(['bin/zsh', '-c', tex_cmd], { 'close_cb': 'RedrawScreen' })
endfunction

" ctrl+l keyboard shortcut to compile LaTeX document
map <silent> <C-l> :call CompileTex()<CR>

"autocmd BufWritePost *.tex :call CompileTex() | noautocmd write

Problem
The new function does not work. When I try to compile using the keyboard shortcut <C-l>, nothing happens.
This is the error:
Reading from channel error...                                                    
executing job failed: No such file or directory

Notably, running the command docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm -v $(pwd):/data latex-dev:1.0.0 latexmk -pdf -silent -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex in another terminal works, so the command is fine.
Question
What is wrong with the function and how can it be fixed? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Have you checked the job status? Probably something causes it to bail out.

Thanks. For some reason, I get: executing job failed: No such file or directory. Updated my post. Why is the file not found?

I know this is not the answer you are looking for but compiling stuff in the background, especially when it involves elements that are outside of Vim's reach, is really not something that should be handled in Vim itself. Yes, it can do "async", now, but the API is too complex.
Let it write the file and let other tools detect such events and do the compilation if needed, in a separate terminal.
In this case, I would start with something like this, using my trusty old entr (untested because, obviously, I don't have all your setup at hand):
$ ls **/*.tex | entr -cp docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm -v $(pwd):/data latex-dev:1.0.0 latexmk -pdf -silent -interaction=nonstopmode /_

And I would probably put the docker run […] command in a Makefile for good measure:
" compile on write in a separate terminal 
$ ls **/*.tex | entr -cp make

" manual compile in a terminal
$ make

" manual compile in Vim
:make

PROs:

it keeps Vim pristine and focused
it uses the right tool for the job
stuff really happens "in the background" so there is no need to redraw anything or handle state in any way in Vim
it lives with your project
it is editor-agnostic
it can be used inside and outside of your editor
it can be used automatically (with entr) AND manually (with :make or $ make)
more tools to learn

CONs:

more tools to learn
not self-contained in Vim


You accidentally listed "more tools to learn" as a con :-)

Well, it's both, really. Fixed.

Note that expand('%:p') gives you the full path to the current file on the host machine. Then you proceed to mount $(pwd) as /data in your Docker container.
You try to pass something with the full host path to Docker.
The path is off.
Let's assume you edit
/home/me/Documents/my_document.tex

Docker will see the file at
/data/my_document.tex

I'd suggest the following untested changes:
function! CompileTex() abort
  let l:tex_file = expand('%:p:t') " <-- only take the file name itself
  let l:pwd = expand('%:p:h')      " <-- path where your file is stored on the host machine
  let tex_cmd = 'docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm -v ' .. l:pwd .. ':/data latex-dev:1.0.0 latexmk -pdf -silent -interaction=nonstopmode ' .. l:tex_file
  let s:job = job_start(['bin/zsh', '-c', tex_cmd], { 'close_cb': 'RedrawScreen' })
endfunction

Using %:p:h to get the path where your file is stored is also more robust than to rely on the pwd shell command.
If you start Vim from a different directory or :cd, your file may not be in your working directory.
See :help filename-modifiers (or just :help %:p) for details.
One last thing
Both Ctrl-P and Ctrl-L are useful commands you should not shadow. If you really want to use those keys (and after you've read the respective :help sections), at least :nnoremap them.

Thanks. I made suggested changes, but still get the error No such file or directory. (Also changed to a different keyboard shortcut.)

@anti-destin probably your working directory in Docker is still off. Either change it to /data or prefix the path to the file you pass like 'docker ... /data/' .. l:tex_file.

You might also want to :echo the command instead of running it. You should quickly spot where it goes wrong.

I ended up taking a different approach and now send the command to a terminal:
" Function to compile a tex file into a pdf
function CompileTex() abort
  const term_buf = term_start(&shell, { 'vertical': 1, 'term_cols': 60, 'term_finish': 'close' })
  const l:tex_file = expand('#')
  const l:tex_cmd = 'docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm -v $(pwd):/data latex-dev:1.0.0 latexmk -pdf -silent -interaction=nonstopmode ' . l:tex_file . ' && reloadPreview && exit'
  call term_sendkeys(term_buf, l:tex_cmd . "\<CR>")
endfunction

" Comma + t keyboard shortcut to compile LaTeX document
nnoremap <silent> ,t :call CompileTex()<CR>

This works (although I am not sure how to replace $(pwd) in the terminal). Now I just need to see how to prevent the focus from changing.
